# How to pass data from Partial View into View - MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Please Read :) thanks in advance :)
 I have View called RMA (http://localhost/User/RMA?Id=132), which i show some details about a product and i also display Comments (List) which is related to that product and There is also the possibility to update each Comments in same view, but first of all i should get Comments by id and than i can update each comments in same view, but i do have some problems to get comments by id in same view, where i also display list of comments .let me describe issue :)

- When i tried to Display Comments by id 
  http://localhost/User/CommentsId?ComID=155&id=132 
   or 
   http://localhost/User/CommentsId?ComID=145&id=132 
  "NOT in same view - everything is going to work"

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CommentsId(int? ComID, int? id)
{

    //Show Comment per ID
    var querythree = (from RH in db.RMA_History

                      join RB in db.Besked on RH.Id equals RB.RMAID

                      where RB.ID == ComID && RB.RMAID == id

                      select new VMRMA
                      {
                          RBID = RB.ID,
                          RBPM = RB.MSG,
                          RBRMAID = RB.RMAID


                      });

    var q = querythree.FirstOrDefault();

    return View(q);

}
```

View (CommentsId.cshtml):

```
@using ModelNameSpace.Models
@model VMRMA
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CommentsById</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <input type="hidden" name="ComID" value="@Model.RBID" />
        <input type="hidden" name="RMAID" value="@Model.RBRMAID" />

        <p>@Model.RBPM</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The View which is RMA , where user click on Update Link:

```
@using NameSpace.Models
@model VMRMA

//Loop Comments
 @foreach (var item in Model.Comment_Lists)
{
 <h3 class="h5">@item.PM</h3>

//Link 
 <a  href="/User/CommentsId?ComID=@item.ID&id=@item.RMAID">Update</a>
}
```

---

- But when i tried to display comments by id inside same view RMA 
  http://localhost/User/RMA?Id=132 
   by using PartialView and when i check if its works or not , i can see popup where it display comment its empty and its not contains any data!

Controller:

```
public ActionResult _CommentsById(int? ComID , int? id)
{


    var querythree = (from RH in db.RMA_History

                      join RB in db.Besked on RH.Id equals RB.RMAID

                      where  RB.ID == ComID && RB.RMAID == id

                      select new VMRMA
                      {  
                          RBID =RB.ID,
                          RBPM =RB.MSG,
                          RBRMAID=RB.RMAID


                      });

    var q = querythree.FirstOrDefault();

    return PartialView("_CommentsById", q);

}
```

PartialView (_CommentsById.cshtml):

```
@using ModelNameSpace.Models
@model VMRMA
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CommentsById</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <input type="hidden" name="ComID" value="@Model.RBID" />
        <input type="hidden" name="RMAID" value="@Model.RBRMAID" />

        <p>@Model.RBPM</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The View RMA ,where Render the PartialView:

```
    @using NameSpace.Models
    @model VMRMA  
//Select From Parent Model HRMAS

<input type="text" class="form-control disabled" value="@Model.HRMAs.FirmaNavn">

//Loop Comments list

     @foreach (var item in Model.Comment_Lists)
    {
     <h3 class="h5">@item.PM</h3>

    //Link 
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="/User/_CommentsById?ComID=@item.ID&id=@item.RMAID">Update</a>

    }

    <div class="container">

     <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

         <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content--
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div>

       <div class="modal-body">
             @Html.Partial("_CommentsById")
                         </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

RMA Controller:

```
public ActionResult RMA(int? id, VMRMA model)
{

    //List comments
      var queryTwo = (from RH in db.RMA_History

                   join RB in db.Besked on RH.Id equals RB.RMAID

                   where RB.RMAID == id 

                   select new VMRMA.Comment_List
                   {
                      //Select Something

                   });

      var query = (from RH in db.RMA_History
                   join RS in db.RMAStatus on RH.StatusID equals RS.ID

                  where RH.Id == id


                   select new VMRMA.HRMA
                   {
                     //Select Something


                   });



    model.HRMAs = query.FirstOrDefault();
    model.Comment_Lists = queryTwo.ToList();


    return View(model);
   }
```

ViewModel VMRMA :

```
 public class VMRMA
    {
        public int? RBID { get; set; }
        public string RBPM { get; set; }
        public int? RBRMAID { get; set; }
        public Comment_PM Comment_PMs { get; set; }

        public class Comment_PM
        {

            public Comment_PM()
            {

            }

            public Comment_PM(string PM, int? ID, DateTime Date, string Forfatter, string whos, int? RMAID)
            {
                this.PM = PM;
                this.ID = ID;
                this.Date = Date;
                this.Forfatter = Forfatter;
                this.whos = whos;
                this.RMAID = RMAID;

            }

            public int? ID { get; set; }

            public string PM { get; set; }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            public string Forfatter { get; set; }

            public string whos { get; set; }

            public int? RMAID { get; set; }


        }
------------------------------

   public HRMA HRMAs { get; set; }

      public class HRMA
        {
          public HRMA(string FirmaNavn)
          {
                this.FirmaNavn = FirmaNavn;
           }

           public string FirmaNavn{ get; set; }
        }
------------------------------

   public List<Comment_List> Comment_Lists { get; set; }

        public class Comment_List
        {

            public Comment_List()
            {

            }

            public Comment_List(string PM, int? ID, DateTime Date, string Forfatter , string whos , int? RMAID)
            {
                this.PM = PM;
                this.ID = ID;
                this.Date = Date;
                this.Forfatter = Forfatter;
                this.whos = whos;
                this.RMAID = RMAID;

            }

            public int? ID { get; set; }

            public string PM { get; set; }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            public string Forfatter { get; set; }

            public string whos { get; set; }

            public int? RMAID { get; set; }


        }



    }
```

---

- Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction ! why when i trying display comment by id inside same view using Partial View , its can not retrieve data and i think its bcuz cant pass ComID value to controller,when i try to use inside RMA view ,so how can i get ComID value and than pass it into RMA Controller ?!
- But when i using different view to display comments by id it will retrieve data
- or how can i use Ajax to get content of PartialView and than replace it in RMA View
- or any suggestion how can i display comments by id in same View and than update comments.

  Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You need to use the overload which passes the `Model` in to the partial.  `@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName", customViewData)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @nurdyguy it did something like this in my View , but still no luck   @Html.Partial("_CommentsById", Model)